# TableViewController using SDWebImage with UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode6, sdwebimage

Good afternoon,

Im trying to use SDWebImage in my TableViewController for the first time and I have some problems using the "setImageWithURL" property because it only admits a UIImageView but I have a UIImage in order to parse the data from my JSON.

How I have to change my code in order to use a UIImageView instead of a UIImage? Because UIImageView doesn't have the same functions as UIImage and I have to create my Image from a URL.

Here is my code, I hope you can help me with some tips:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";
    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView

                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...

    cell.makeLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    cell.likes.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"likes"];
    cell.comments.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"];
    cell.username.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
    cell.refuser.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user_ref"];
    cell.modelLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];

    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage * carPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

    /*[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];*/

    NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];
    NSData * imageData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL2];
    UIImage * carPhoto2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];
    cell.profileImage.image = carPhoto2;

    return cell;

}
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: you can use as :  NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]]; [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:imageurl
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

Comment: try `[cell.carImage sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: imageURL]];` and `[cell.profileImage sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: imageURL2]];`

Answer (score 0):

change your code as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";
CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView

                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell...

cell.makeLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
cell.likes.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"likes"];
cell.comments.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"];
cell.username.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];
cell.refuser.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user_ref"];
cell.modelLabel.text = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];

NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];

[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];

[cell.profileImage setImageWithURL:imageURL2
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];



return cell;

}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Much appreciated for your answer @ismail, I hope it works. I'm going to test the code tonigh and I will see.

Comment: Also I want to know if now that I'm going to create a UIImageView using the SDWebImage, I have to turn my "profileImage" to a UIImageView instead of a UIImage in my ".h file", is that correct?

Comment: Thanks again @ismail. So I'm going to have to add a UIImageView in my Storyboard instead of a UIImage? Sorry for asking those "newbie" questions, but it´s my first time using SDWebImage and UIImageView instead of UIImage and there things I need to know regarding that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to just add two lines when you are using `SDWebImage`

```
[cell.carImage sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: imageURL]];
[cell.profileImage sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: imageURL2]];
```

and remove below lines

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * carPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

/*[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];*/

NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];
NSData * imageData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL2];
UIImage * carPhoto2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];
cell.profileImage.image = carPhoto2;
```

Comment: Thanks @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani. What's exactly "sd_setImageWithUrl"...? sd...? Thanks again.

Comment: @J123_lock it is category method which is created by SDWebImage Library in `UIImageView+Webcache` class.

Comment: And what happends if I only use "setImageWithUrl" instead of "sd_setImageWithUrl". It is the same?

Comment: if you are using old classes of SDWebImage they used `setImageWithUrl ` . but in updated library they deprecated `setImageWithUrl` and add new method called  `sd_setImageWithUrl`. same as ios deprecate such methods :). implement this and click on `sd_setImageWithUrl`. it will take you to `UIImageView+Webcache.m`. then you may know all things.they wrote there all this things.

Comment: Thanks again man, you saved me ;) Also I want to know if now that I'm going to create a UIImageView using the SDWebImage, I have to turn my "carImage" to a UIImageView instead of a UIImage in my ".h file", is that correct? And also in my Storyboard?

Comment: yes you have to make carImage as `UIImageView`. when you call `[cell.carImage sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: imageURL]];` that library will set image in `carImage` directly.

Comment: @J123_lock if answer is helpful then accept is as an answer.